# Android touch event propagation

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

It's my understanding that Android event propagation goes from parent to child, that is to say, it starts with the outermost element and inwards from there. My question is, why is it that when I try to scroll vertically a listview that is inside a viewpager that is wrapped on a scrollview, the listview moves, and not the viewpager.
Okay, let me rephrase that: 
I'm trying to create a menu that appears when the user pulls down the view pager, let me make that even clearer:

Scrollview
   My custom Menu
   ViewPager (with three fragments, all of them have a lisview)
      ListView

I understand that what I'm trying to do is a bit odd, but bear with me just for this time. :)

What can I do to "disable" momentarily the list views scrolling.

Thanks

Comment: Disable intercepting touch events, requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()

Comment: For anyone else who finds, here's a really useful explanation of what is actually happening: http://codetheory.in/understanding-android-input-touch-events/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have to override the scrolling event. A good webpage is [Disable scrolling in Android ListView](http://danosipov.com/?p=604) .
Mainly look at `dispatchTouchEvent`. Snippet of it:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int actionMasked = ev.getActionMasked() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // Ignore move events
        return true;
    }
```

Personally I wish it is simpler than this like disabling scroll method.

Comment: makes perfect sense. that did the trick. it's odd that this happened though, as the documentation explicitly says the events navigate from parent to child. Nevertheless, thanks for your workaround! :)